# Problem with Android backup file? How to read it?

Tags: java, android, backup, restore

The example [BackupRestore - Backup and Restore](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/index.html) runs successfully. But, I can't understand the backup file, because, I can't read that file. How can I use the file? Can anyone clarify this doubt for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) is a cloud based service. There are no locally stored backup files. The backup service stores them somewhere in the google cloud.